# Android studio_activity con elemento

Tags: android, android-studio

quiero poder a mi activity que tiene una imageButton de tenga un valor de 7500 y que al hacer clik este valor se guarde y seguir sumando entre mas elementos de otra activity.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir como texto, las imagenes son dificiles de ver

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que preguntas, yo guardaría el valor que has hecho click en una variable 
y luego pasarlo a la otra activity para poder sumarlo con otros valores. 
Lo pondría en el intento.

```
Intent cambiarPantalla=new Intent(activityActual.this,siguienteActivity.class);
Bundle datos=new Bundle();
datos.putInt("ClaveDelValor",valor);
canviPantalla.putExtras(datos);

startActivity(cambiarPantalla);
```

Y en la siguiente activity lo recogeria para sumarlo con otro.

```
Intent recibirValor = getIntent();
int valorDelActivityAnterior = recibirValor.getIntExtra("ClaveDelValor");
```